# What is a Row Word™?

Tags: word-property

This puzzle is in the spirit of the [What is a Word/Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22what%20is%20a%22%20word%20is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) with a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Phrase%22%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22What%20is%20%22%20%22Word%22%20-missing%20user%3A463%20is%3Aquestion) puzzles.

If a word is satisfied by a following rule, I call it a Row word. Here is the list of Row words™ and Non-row words™:

| Row Words™ | Non-Row Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| row | column |
| perpetuity | probability |
| ashfall | volcano |
| yippie | happy |
| sad | cry |
| rupturewort | rupturing |
| proprietor | seven |
| wetter | dryer |
| fall | jump |
| all | everywhere |
| rep | exercise |
| typewriter | writing |

**Question:** What is the rule?

Comment: Why down vote??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Row words are words that can be:

> Written on a single row of a qwerty keyboard.

Examples:

> QWERTYUIOP contains all the letters to write TYPEWRITER and PROPRIETOR, but it is missing some of the letters that you would need to write SEVEN or WRITING.